# Pinning Visual Studio projects to start menu

Tags: visual-studio-2013, startmenu, pinning

I am using Windows 7

I have pinned **Google Chrome** to my start menu and I can see a `right arrow` near the icon. When hovering on it I can see tasks as `new window` and `new incognito window`.

Likewise I need to add most commonly worked projects in Visual Studio 2013 to the Visual Studio launcher in Start menu.

How can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: I can see this on my screen. I can go to the recent list and pin these projects using the pin icon next to the project. They are then shown in the pinned projects area at the top.

Comment: @John I am not able to follow you!

Comment: If you have Visual Studio pinned to your start menu, you can then follow the right arrow near the icon. There are then a list of recent projects shown. You can use the pin icon next to each project/solution to add it to your pinned menu. I am using VSCommands in Visual Studio, so I'm not sure if that makes a difference.

Comment: I am not able to see the right arrow that you are mentioning near the Visual Studio icon!

Comment: This is a similar technique using the Taskbar: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/pinning-projects-and-solutions-with-visual-studio-2010

Answer (score 8):

Thank you @John from the comments I found out the answer.

- First I pinned Visual Studio to Task bar.
- Second, dragged the solution file and dropped on the exe on the Task 
  bar (Pinned to Visual Studio)

After the second step, I was able to see the programs to the right side (tasks) of the Visual Studio short cut in the start menu.

Comment: this is a perfect solution!